# What is the pronunciation of 着重?

Tags: word-choice

According to Pleco:

- zháo zhòng: emphasize; attach importance (v) / emphasis (n)
- zhuó zhòng: stress; emphasize (v)

Both use 着重 as its characters. The first one lists a noun as well as a verb as its usage but the second one only lists a verb.

According to 网易有道词典, it only lists the latter.

Usually, if the pronunciation is different, the meaning is differen as well. For example, `zháo` means *touch* while `zhe` works as a particle, even though both are written as 着.

But in this case the meaning looks the same. So why do two forms exist and which one I should use?

Comment: zháo zhòng and zhuó zhòng seems like literary and colloquial versions of the same term 着重.

Comment: The correct pronunciation is zhuó zhòng.

Comment: **Zháo** is the reading used for **着火** (to be set on fire). 漢語大詞典 and 臺灣教育部國語辭典簡編本 both only list **zhuó zhòng**. Also, my Pleco doesn't list **zháo zhòng**; what dictionary is Pleco using for this reading?

Comment: @droooze ABC. I purchased a bundle so it might be an In-App Purchase functionality.

Comment: @TangHo Thanks and then do you know where `zháo zhòng` is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I was born in H.K, I would accept the Hong Kong's standard

/zhuó zhòng/ is the standard reading of 着重

There's a 著 , 着.discussion on this subject here http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?14,139780

著 in 衣**著** is pronounced /yī **zhuó**/

著 is used in place of 着 in Taiwan

In summary:

着= /zháo/

着重 = /**zhuó** zhòng/ (in this compound , 着 is read the same as 著 in 衣著)

**著**重 = /**zhuó** zhòng/ (only in Taiwan)

The editor at Pleco might had considered 着 and 著 the same character in this compound (accepted both Taiwan and mainland China's standard),  and listed both single character's pinyin.

Comment: See [香港小學學習字詞表](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e08iq.png) (web address: www.edbchinese.hk/lexlist_ch/)

Comment: There's a 著 ,  着.discussion on this subject here http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?14,139780

Comment: [Since all dictionaries seem to describe it as zhuó zhòng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkZ1f.png), I think that settles the question. The only other issue for the OP is to decide whether he/she wants to write 着重 or 著重, but given the post history it'll be 着重.

Comment: @droooze  I accept the Hong Kong's standard, and agree 着 /zháo/ in 着重 /zhuó zhòng/ is read the same as 著 /zhuó/. Answer edited